# Interaction change for tab shift

Tags: interaction-design, accessibility, customer-experience

I have a case where i have tabs and each tabs has a set of information.
and in two tabs the top level data is same , So when user switches between them it looks like no change happened it will go unnoticed.
what would be a better way to solve this.
Can any type of interaction between them help or any animation.

Check this image two tabs has same data at starting point.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest combining the two similar tabs into one 'Competitors' tab and including a switch for the different data sets next data that will change when focus is switched.

Answer (score 0):

Fading your content pane out and back in seems to be sufficient. Google Analytics goes further and shows a loading bar to let the user know something is happening.

[image: Google Analytics Loading Screen]
If there is any noticeable loading time, it will have the benefit of [distracting your user](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/35735/101673) too.